# How can I show JSON response in Postman, GET request Express?

Tags: node.js, json, express, mongoose, postman

I am trying to get a single the information for a single user by Id using mongoose and express.The function I have now gives me a 200 status code, but the JSON Object is not showing  up in Postman what am I missing?

I posted both the controller and the model i am using from my files.

controller

```
const express = require("express");

const classworkRouter = express.Router();

const User = require("../../models/User");

classworkRouter.get("/:userId", (req, res) => {
    // const Id = req.params.userId;

        User.findById(req.params.userId).then((err, user)=>{
            if(err) {
                res.status(500);
                console.log("errr 500")
            } else {
                res.json({"user" : user})
            }
        })
       

})



module.exports = classworkRouter;
```

model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ClassworkSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String,
    isDone: false
});

const OutcomesSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String, 
    isDone: false,
    isApproved: false
})

const MeetupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    location: String,
    attended: false
})
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    classwork: [ClassworkSchema],
    outcomes: [OutcomesSchema],
    meetups: [MeetupSchema],
  });



module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Comment: If a user will be not found then just just get an empty object in a response

Comment: Did you checked req.params.userId value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to verify :

1. `req.params.userId` is not empty.
2. As you are using `findById`,the userId must be a valid ObjectId. ie., it must be of the type `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`.
3. Check whether you are passing an existing userId.

Hence, you can do like this :

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
classworkRouter.get("/:userId", (req, res) => {
      const { userId } = req.params;

        if(!userId){
           return res.status(400).json({//handle error })
        }
       
        if(!ObjectId.isValid(userId)){
           return res.status(400).json({//handle error })
        }

        User.findById(userId,(err, user) {
            if(err) {
                res.status(500);
                console.log("errr 500")
            } else {
                if(!user)
                res.status(400).json({message:"user not found"});

                res.status(200).json({"user" : user})
            }
        })
       

})
```

Comment: This worked thank you, also quick question if I wanted to access a nested object in the user and get a that information how exactly could I do that?

Comment: You can simply access it using the dot operator like -> `user.nestedObject.fieldName` or `user[nestedObject["fieldName"]]`

Answer (score 0):

You indicated two parameters in `then` but `then` has 1 parameter - a result of resolved `Promise`. If you need to get a possible error you need to use `catch`:

```js
User.findById(req.params.userId)
    .then((user)=>{
    if(!user) {
         res.status(404).end();
         console.log("user not found")
    } else {
        res.json({"user" : user})
    }})
    .catch((err)=>{
        res.status(500).end();
        console.log("errr 500")
    })
```